# Kotlin coroutines in Android: Why use bg() from Anko instead of async()?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, anko

I started using Kotlin coroutines on Android today and I noticed that Anko has its own set of helper methods for them. I understand why `asReference()` exists, but I can't figure out why `bg()` does, given that the core coroutines lib already has `async()`.

The `bg()` code is quite simple and it uses `async()` inside:

```
@PublishedApi
internal var POOL = newFixedThreadPoolContext(2 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), "bg")

inline fun <T> bg(crossinline block: () -> T): Deferred<T> = async(POOL) {
    block()
}
```

So what is the advantage of using `bg()` instead of `async()`? Is `async()` inefficient in some way for Android apps?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, `bg` uses `POOL` as its `CoroutineDispatcher`, read about it [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#coroutine-context-and-dispatchers).

Basically this function only exists to wrap the pool in which these tasks are executed. Using `async` directly would require you to provide one. So in the end, each task started via `bg` is ensured to be executed in the same pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @s1m0nw1, however, `async` doesn't require you to provide a pool, that is optional and it uses the `CommonPool` by default, so what is the advantage of `bg` using  a different pool?

Comment: Yes but you do not have control over `CommonPool`, right? Maybe the `POOL` needs to be controlled in some way. That's why they define there own pool instance which is used in `bg`

Comment: Since you said "maybe" I think that is a guess on your side @s1m0nw1. I already could see from the code that they use a different pool, I posted the question so that someone can explain why that is. Thanks again for your answer but I need more concrete information on whether there is a good reason to use `bg` and what that reason is.

Comment: I am almost in the same as you, also asked my question if you want to know more or simple answer, feel free:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461766/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-anko-coroutines-extensions