# What is the correct way of using Anko Coroutines extensions?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, anko

So I am migrating an example app from RxJava to Kotlin/Anko Corountines and I am wondering if I am doing the best (first) approach of it:

```
fun getPopulationList() {
    val ref = asReference()

    async(UI) {
        try {
            ref().setCurrentState(ViewState.State.LOADING)
            val background = bg {
                repository.populationResponse().execute().body()
            }

            ref().let {
                it.response = background.await()
                it.mvpView?.onGetData(it.response)
                it.setCurrentState(ViewState.State.FINISH)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            ref().mvpView?.onError(e)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using an MVP architecture where my `Presenter` base class had a `CompositeSubscription` and in the `onDestroy`'s fragment or activity method simple unsubscribe and clear the `CompositeSubscription` object. But i am wondering if the `asReference()` function from Anko Coroutines does the same and there is no need to save a list of `Deferred<T>` and then iterate it and cancel one by one.

BTW if I add a `Thread.sleep(5000)` to simulate a big transaction and destroy the Fragment I can see in the logcat the HTTP response even after the fragment is not visible/destroyed while with RxJava doesn't happen, so I think I am not using properly.

**UPDATE**

```
 fun getPopulationList() {
    val ref = asReference()

    job = launch(UI) {

        try {
            ref().setCurrentState(ViewState.LOADING)
            val background = bg {
                Thread.sleep(5000) //simulate heavy IO

                if (isActive) {
                    repository.populationResponse().execute().body()
                } else {
                    return@bg null
                }
            }

            ref().let {
                it.response = background.await()
                it.mvpView?.onGetData(it.response)
                it.setCurrentState(ViewState.FINISH)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            RestHttpExceptionHandler().handle(UI, e, ref())
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to cancel the coroutine while calling `job.cancel()` in `onDestroy()` method but to make it work I have to check if the job is active or not and that translate into an if/else and a return or not data. Is there any better way to return something when the job was cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [asReference()](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/generated/coroutines/src/weakReferenceSupport.kt) source it is nothing other than a weak reference and invoke method to get reference that throws `CancellationException` when object is collected. it does not do anything to cancel operation. just is **aware of collected object**.

so you need to keep reference of a [Job](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/core/kotlinx-coroutines-core/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/Job.kt) or subtype of it to cancel operation.

`launch` coroutine builder from [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) returns a Job instance. here is an example:

```
private lateinit var job: Job

private fun startCoroutines() {
    val ref = asReference()
    job = launch(UI) {
        try {
            val deferred = async(parent = coroutineContext[Job]) {
                    //do some work
                    result//return
            }

            ref().setData(deferred.await())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}
```

Notes:

1- when result type is not important `launch` can be used instead of `async`.

2- to do cancellation in child coroutines you must create parent/child job hierarchies. I passed parent(`launch`) `Job` reference to child coroutine(async) to achieve this.

3- as ***cancellation is cooperative*** cancellation implementation must be done in async(see examples [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#cancellation-and-timeouts)).

3- `job.cancel()` is used in onDestroy cancels job and it's child async. this can be done in Presenter in MVP pattern.

Comment: Thanks! Really great answer! Will try it tomorrow. Didn't catch the 2 point about cancel child coroutines. Anyway really great answer. If cancellation is cooperative a HTTP connection cannot be cancelled right?

Comment: Thanks. coroutines didn't know anything about what is cancelation meaning in your case. It just send a signal and you will get it with check of isActive(see cancelation examples in above link). For http Retrofit have cancel mechanism.

Comment: Can you check my original post? updated with your comments.

Comment: @NicolasJafelle your question is going to get big and multi topical. it's better to ask a new question.